# singleton class misuse, c++ - explanation needed

Tags: c++

I just came across what i tought wasn't possible in c++ (i am learning it)

I called a nonstatic function without initializing the class(singleton class) object or wtf happend, im not grasping it, this was == NULL and the way i did it was -

my singleton class example:

```
class LightsLogic {

public:
    void LightsLogic::request_color_shift_group_after_x_msecs(blabla);

    int current_used_chase_list = 0;

// ALL THE SINGLETON CLASS THING BELOW
private:

    LightsLogic() {  // CONSTRUCTOR HERE !
    };

    LightsLogic(LightsLogic const&);    // Don't Implement. // SINGLETON
    void operator=(LightsLogic const&); // Don't implement // SINGLETON

public:

    static LightsLogic& getInstance()  // return reference. // SINGLETON
    {
        static LightsLogic instance;
        return instance;
    }

};
```

so somewhere i defined:

```
static LightsLogic* logicofligths;
```

and then i called method from this class

```
logicofligths->request_color_shift_group_after_x_msecs(blabla);
```

now what happend were - this method used variable:

```
void LightsLogic::request_color_shift_group_after_x_msecs(blabla) {
    current_used_chase_list; // i am doing something with this variable
   //but since this variable was defined and initialized in class header
   // and this == null, this method CANT acces this variable ?! but it thinks it can ?!
   //we do get a crash saying: First-chance exception at 0x013F5E8B in myexe.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00028D48.

  // and if we would use this check before accesing the variable :
if (this == NULL) {
report("this is null");
return;
}
//this would prevent the crash.

}
```

now the correct way of accesing the method of this singleton class without ruining it is:

```
(&LightsLogic::getInstance())->request_color_shift_group_after_x_msecs(blabla);
//i know i could just use LightsLogic::getInstance(). but that im using for accesing variables, more clear for me and compiler should fix this misery on compile ?!
```

why was i able to do this and what was i doing wrong ? Or this isnt the case of doing anything wrong and i just misused some memory and getting 'undefined behaviour' ? cause that was my first tought.

the funny part is - application works if i dont use variables defined in class header of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling via nullpointer has Undefined Behavior.

Anything or nothing can happen.

Comment: anything defines nothing too, dont you think ? so by just using static LightsLogic* logicofligths; i accessed class wrong ? why did it let me to do this ? :|

Comment: There is no way to restrict the permitted operations on a pointer. The value of the pointer, even if known, isn't considered wrt. compilation. But the compiler can *warn* about it, if you up the warning level. I'd try that.